# Remove Control Array Designation At Design Time

Tags: vb6

During design time when creating a form, I accidentally created a control array.  That control was copied and pasted to several other controls.  Is it possible to remove the control array designation without deleting and re-creating the controls?

This is all at design time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have ended up creating a Text3 control array with 5 elements, the easiest way to correct this by hand is to rename the elements one by one to unique names and then clear the Index property of each one.

If you are cautious *and you know what you are doing* it can be faster to edit the .FRM or .CTL file in Notepad.